# Get the row id in TableViewRow

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

The following code to print the "local" model in tableview, its working, now my problem is to fetch the row id or row detail by clicking the each row. I have attached the **showDetail** function on each row to get the row detail.But unable to get the row attch data. How can i achieve this please help me, I really appreciate your answers.

```
<TableView dataCollection="local">
    <TableViewRow onClick="showDetail">
        <View layout="horizontal">
            <ImageView image="{image}" width="50" height="50"/>
            <Label id="name" text="{title}"></Label>
        </View>
    </TableViewRow>
</TableView>


function showDetail(e){
console.log(e.index);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of the showDetail function?

Comment: please see my edit. Nothing is there i just console the e.index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the TableView API click Event:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-event-click

There are all properties: e.g. *index*=the number of the row

And have a look at *row* and *rowData*

Comment: thanks for your reply, i got the index inside the e but unable to retrieve, by e.index. it showing undefined.  Could you please help me here.

Comment: try e.rowData[e.index]

Comment: just saw your edit, try moving the click event to the tableview, not tableviewrow.

Comment: thanks thanks really thanks, I have made a very silly mistake.